# How to update table1 field by using other table and function

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update

I have two table and one function,

Table1 contains `shop_code,batch_id,registry_id`

```
shop_code| batch_id|registry_id   
123 | 100  |12
124 | 100  |13
125 | 100  |12
```

Table2  `contains shop_code,shop_name`

```
shop_code| shop_name   
123 | need to populate  
124 | need to populate  
125 | need to populate
```

Function1 take parameter `registry_id` from table1 and returns `shop_name`

Table2 shop_name is empty I want to populate against the shop_code.

I have tried my best but all effort is gone in vain.
It will be great if someone can help I am using Oracle.

I tried below code but giving error on from keyword

```
 update TABLE2 set T2.SHOP_NAME = T.SHOP_NAME
 from(
 select GET_shop_name(t1.registry_id) as shop_name ,
           t1.shop_code shop_code
           from TABLE1 T1 
                ) t where t.shop_code = t1.shop_code;
```

Comment: Even if your attempts were in vain, you still should post what you've tried.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger yeah I update by question please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement.

Something like this might work:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE2 t2
USING (
  SELECT GET_shop_name(t1.batch_id) AS shop_name ,
  t1.shop_code shop_code
  FROM TABLE1 T1 ) t1
ON (t2.shop_code = t1.shop_code)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET t2.shop_name = t1.shop_name
;
```

You'll have to excuse if the exact code above doesn't work I don't have SQL Dev where I am right now for syntax details. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely 100% sure if I got your question right, but I believe you want something like

```
update
  table2 u
set
  shop_name = (
    select
      get_shop_name(t1.batch_id)
    from
      table1 t1
    where
      t1.chop_code = u.shop_code
   );
```

Comment: I need to also pass batch_id at run time in query

Answer (score 2):

can you try this approach try to put inner query to get shop name value; I have not tested it but I think approach will work for you.

```
update TABLE2 T2
   set T2.SHOP_NAME =
       (select GET_shop_name(t1.batch_id, t1.shop_code) from table1 t1 wehre t1.shop_code = t2.shop_code)
 where T2.shop_name is null
```